# Meaning of "now that"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> One wild cart ride later they stood blinking in the sunlight outside Gringotts. **Harry didn't know where to run first *now that* he had a bag full of money**.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

["Now that" means *since*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/now_that). Then the highlighted sentence can be replaced by "(1) Harry didn't know where to run first (2) since he had a bag full of money." Semantically, this is somewhat awkward; I think that (1) cannot be the consequence of (2).

What's the exact meaning of the highlighted sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core sense of *now that* is that *now*, in the present, one thing has been accomplished, and what follows—the “consequence”—is in operation in the present, and/or lies ahead, in the future. But what is in the future may or may not be known; and *now that* is very often used in situations where it is not known.

> Now that he had graduated, he was ready to look for a job.  *OR*
>   Now that he had graduated, he had no idea what he would do next.

Harry's case parallels the latter: this thing is done, what is the next thing to do?

Answer (score 3):

StoneyB's answer is correct, but some additional examples that are equivalent to  *now that* may help.  (That is, these examples and variations upon them can substitute for *now that* in the sentence in the question without much altering the meaning.)

> • it now being the case that
>   • it being the case that now
>   • present circumstances being such that